SoftWrap in PyCharm doesnt work if I type a new function around the existing one
I have a bug I can't get around: auto-complete of the brackets works great, but when it gets to soft wrapping a function, so say I typed: round --> enter --> x
would result in UI producing ''round(x)''
Now if while being on the same line I click on the the 'home' button returning me to the start of the line; and then type another function say 'print' and then add a bracket '(' there is just no way I can get it to add another bracket AFTER 'round(x)' so it results in print(round(x))?
Could you assist?
The peculiar thing is that it worked once and then after double shifting and toggling it to see if it worked it stoppped. I went as far as uninstalling the soft and paths and configs, rebooting and installing it all over again but could not get it to work afterwards...
Using a latest commercial version on Win 10
-I tried all soft wraps available to toggle from double shift search menu as well as the left side of the console [where lines are indicated]

all the 'insert brackets in the end' options
I uninstalled and installed the software again and nothing
tried adding *.py for wrapping and still nothing

Can anyone tell me how to manually add it into the soft as everything the recommend on the website does not work
